# Best way to develop a WP-site on multiple machines

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, localhost

I'm busy working on my portfolio and I have a localhost setup. I use Wordpress as my CMS.

Since I'm not always home, I'd like to work on this project when on other machines (not on the same network, indeed).

What am I to do? Should I setup another localhost on the other computer and copy the wp files to over there? If so, how do I do that without mixing things up?

I've searched on Google for an answer but couldn't find any that solve my problem.

Comment: Simply copy the data from the other machine plus make an export of your database and import this database on the other machine. You could also use something like git to keep multiple machines using the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

If the PCs at both locations run Windows, your solution would be to make a portable (USB stick/pen drive) installation of XAMPP + WordPress (+ your site).

A shortcut would be to make the portable XAMPP install, then install/use the [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) plugin (on the working site) to migrate it over to the USB drive, which will save you the trouble of installing WordPress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Once the portable install is ready, you just use it wherever, and your site will never go out of sync. :-)

Here is a nice guide to portable installation:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-a-usb-stick-using-xampp/

Hope this works for you.